# No album art and random order bug in elementary OS 0.4 Loki music app (Noise)

Tags: release-loki, music

I have a collection of 111 music albums (around 7.7GB) on my elementary OS session. I did a clean install of 0.4 Loki, imported my collection to Music and got this as a result:

[image: random organization of music on the Albums view in Music]

- No album covers, is there a workaround for this?
- Why is my collection not organized alphabetically on the Albums view?
- Not only that, but every time I close and re-open the Music app, the
  order of the albums on the Albums view changes randomly.

Never had this problem in 0.2 Luna or 0.3 Freya.

Comment: I reported this as a bug in Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1624087

Comment: I'm having this issue both on my desktop and on my laptop.

Comment: I asked about this on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/57nr8g/random_organization_of_albums_view_in_noise_app/

Comment: I asked about this on Google+: https://plus.google.com/+JavierBastardo/posts/8NWqn1viyHc

Comment: I can also verify this is a problem. I would add that the man page for noise isn't really helpful at all either. I do understand that this is programmed by an individual, and if I could pay to fix this, I would. As it is, the intended functionality of eOS is woefully lacking. It is my understanding that the one of the ideas behind this OS is that the user could simply install and get to work right away, without the need to install third party apps, but this is simply not possible.

Comment: Another potentially related bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/noise/+bug/1215558